# Find $a$ such that the minimum and maximum distance from a point to the curve $x^2+y^2=a$ are $\sqrt{5}$ and $3\sqrt{5}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

**Context:** I have to solve the following problem: find $a\in \mathbb{R},\, a>0\,\, /$ the minimum and maximum distance from $(4,2)$ to the curve $x^2+y^2=a$ are $\sqrt{5}$ and $3\sqrt{5}$ respectively.

I can't use polar coordinates. I decided to used Lagrange multipliers.

**Problem:** after using Lagrange multipliers I got this system:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x-4}{x}=\frac{y-2}{y} \\
x^2+y^2=a
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
And then I add one more equation to the system: $5=(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2$ and $45=(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2$, so I have to find the $a$ that satisfies both system of equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x-4}{x}=\frac{y-2}{y} \\
x^2+y^2=a \\
5=(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
and
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x-4}{x}=\frac{y-2}{y} \\
x^2+y^2=a \\
45=(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
The thing is that I can't resolve those systems, I already tried a lot of ways but I never get a result. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Let $a=b^2$ where $b\ge0$

WLOG any point on $$x^2+y^2=b^2$$ be $P(b\cos t,b\sin t)$

Now $$(b\cos t-4)^2+(b\sin t-2)^2=20+b^2-4b(2\cos t+\sin t)$$

Again $$-\sqrt{2^2+1^2}\le-(2\cos t+\sin t)\le\sqrt{2^2+1^2}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. Besides, I can't see where to use that the maximum and minimum distance are $3\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @cor, So $$(3\sqrt5)^2=b^2+20+4b\sqrt5$$ with $b\ge0$ right?

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! so while evaluating the minimum it would be $5=b^2+20-4b\sqrt{5}$, right?

Comment: @cor, you are correct

Answer (score 3):

The point $(4,2)$ lies on the line $y=\frac{1}{2}x$ which passes through the center of the circle.

Now the minimum and maximum is happened in the two intersection points of the line and the circle.

Comment: "The point $(4,2)$ lies on the line $y=\frac{x}{2}$", sorry but why?

Comment: Generally, we consider the line passing through the given point and the center of the circle; in this case $(4,2)$ and $(0,0)$ which is $y=x/2$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a different approach altogether. If $(4,2)$ is inside the circle of radius $\sqrt{a}$, then the minimum and maximum distances combine into one diameter, hence
$$
2a = d = \sqrt{5} + 3\sqrt{5} = 4\sqrt{5}
$$
and the point of interest is $a = \sqrt{2^2+4^2} = \sqrt{20} = 2\sqrt{5}$ away, which means the point $(4,2)$ cannot be inside the circle.

Then the diameter of the circle is exactly the difference between the distances, i.e.
$$
2a = d = 3\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{5} = 2\sqrt{5},
$$
and so the radius must be $a = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very intuitive answer. I should be able to do it Lagrange multipliers tho because sometimes is not a circumference but another type of curve, but I really appreciate your help. I will keep trying to solve the system of equations.

Comment: Besides, a more formal way to say that $P=(4,2)$ cannot be inside the circle could be something like "[...] and $||P||=\sqrt{4^2+2^2}=2\sqrt{5}$. But we said that $d_a=4\sqrt{5}$, this means that $r_a=2\sqrt{a}$, so $||P||=r_a$, and this is absurd because therefore the minimun distance from $P$ to the curve would be $0$ and the maximum distance would be $4\sqrt{5}$ and this is not true because of the hypothesis (with $d_a$ and $r_a$ the diameter and the radius of the curve $y^2+x^2=a$)."?

Comment: @cor1.1.29 sure that would work

Comment: @cor1.1.29 not sure what you are trying to do with Lagrange multipliers. How do your systems model the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: We can solve our problems in any way, as long as we prove everything in a kind of formal way. The thing is that usually in this kind of exercise we have to to some sort of optimization of a function with a restriction. This one was more simple, and could be solve in a more graphical way, but usually the function and the area of restriction is more complex so we have to use lagrange multipliers or some kind of parametrization, so i was practicing for that.

Comment: @cor1.1.29 this is fine, I don't understand what you are trying to optimize with your system. How does your system help solve your problem?

Comment: I used $f(x,y)=(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2$, and  $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2+a$. Also, $\nabla g(x,y)\neq 0$ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. So basically I have a function (the distance from the point $(4,2)$) that I want to optimize in a restriction, which is my $g$ function. That's why I use Lagrange multipliers, and I got that system.

Answer (score 0):

It can be geometrically seen that once you draw the diameter of the circle that passes through $(4,2)$, contributes the maximum and minimum distances. That diameter must have an equation like $y={x\over2}$ which together with $x^2+y^2=a$, leads to two points $(2\sqrt{a\over 5},\sqrt{a\over 5})$ and $(-2\sqrt{a\over 5},-\sqrt{a\over 5})$. The right choice for $a$ is then straightforward, but the problem may or may not have a solution.